# Getting street type in an address

Tags: php

I have a string containing an address and I need to know which street type that address is using. Here is an example:

```
$street = "100 road Overflow";
$streetTypes = array("ROAD", "ST", "ABBEY", "BLVD", "ALLEY", "CAR");

//find and save the street type in a variable

//Response
echo "We have found ".$streetType." in the string";
```

Also, the address is submitted by a user and the format is never the same which complicate things. So far, I've seen format like these:

```
100 ROAD OVERFLOW
100,road Overflow
100, Overflow road
```

What's the best way to address this problem?

Comment: Here is an answer already posted:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795789/check-if-string-contains-word-in-array. Not exactly what you need, but pretty close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with your string, and the set of words you're looking for:

```
$street = "100 road Overflow";
$streetTypes = array("ROAD", "ST", "ABBEY", "BLVD", "ALLEY", "CAR");
```

first convert the string to uppercase and split it using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php). The regex I used will split it on whitespace or commas. You may have to experiment with it to get something that works based on your varying input.

```
$street_array = preg_split('/[\s*|,]/', strtoupper($street));
```

After the original string is an array, you can use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to return any words that match the target set of words.

```
$matches = array_intersect($streetTypes, $street_array);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the matched words. If you only want to show one match, you should prioritize your list in `$streetTypes` so the the most important match is first (if there is such a thing). Then you can display it using:

```
if ($matches) {
    echo reset($matches);
}
```

(You should not use `$matches[0]` to show the first match, because keys will be preserved in `array_intersect` and the first item may not have index zero.)

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
$street = "100 road Overflow";
$streetTypes = array("ROAD", "ST", "ABBEY", "BLVD", "ALLEY", "CAR");

//find and save the street type in a variable
foreach($streetTypes as $item) {
    $findType = strstr(strtoupper($street), $item);
    if($findType){
        $streetType = explode(' ', $findType)[0];
    }
    break;
}

if(isset($streetType)) {
    echo "We have found ".$streetType." in the string";
} else {
    echo "No have found street Type in the string";
}
```